# Limit monthly bandwidth in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I have search all over in google but didn't find any solution.

Is there a way I can limit the total monthly bandwidth per site on php-fpm and
nginx install ( Ubuntu 15.10) ?

**I'm not looking for a web panel solution**

I want to host a few clients on my vps, but limit each one of them.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe ask on [Software Recommendations Stackexchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), fits better.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look for Virtualmin [(Control Managment for website and more)](http://yusufarslan.net/choosing-control-panel-server-management)

I am not sure you can do it with nginx in a box tools

Comment: Thanks, I search for non panel solution but the products looks great. 
didn't saw any section about bandwidth but will check it.

Comment: Virtualmin have Bandwidth setting for each website you add, you can setup also Webmin(Included in Virtualmin) for each client you have, with their password and permissions.